# How to change Label font size in Python FMX GUI app

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey

I'm using the [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) and trying to change the font size on a `Label` component, but it's not working.

I have the following code to create the `Form` and the `Label` on my Form:

```
from delphifmx import *

class HelloForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "ScreenCenter"

        self.myLabel = Label(self)
        self.myLabel.Parent = self
        self.myLabel.Text = "Hello World!"
        self.myLabel.Align = "Client"
        self.myLabel.TextSettings.Font.Size = 50
        self.myLabel.TextSettings.HorzAlign = "Center"
```

My output Form, then looks like this:
[image: Python GUI Hello World]

My "Hello World!" Label should be much bigger than what it's showing. I'm setting the font size with this piece of code:

```
self.myLabel.TextSettings.Font.Size = 50
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah. After playing with the code for a bit, I realized that I needed to add the following line of code in order to make sure the `Label` isn't being styled by the Style Manager:

```
self.myLabel.StyledSettings = ""
```

If you don't clear the `StyledSettings`, then it will use default styling on the Label component. After adding that line of code, my Label now works and shows correctly:
[image: Python GUI Hello World]

So my full code now looks like this and works:

```
from delphifmx import *

class HelloForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "ScreenCenter"

        self.myLabel = Label(self)
        self.myLabel.Parent = self
        self.myLabel.Text = "Hello World!"
        self.myLabel.Align = "Client"
        self.myLabel.StyledSettings = ""
        self.myLabel.TextSettings.Font.Size = 50
        self.myLabel.TextSettings.HorzAlign = "Center"

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "Hello World"
    Application.MainForm = HelloForm(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```